# She IS going to be sleeping at 7 in the morning! I am a Spanish speaker and there is something I don´t understand in this sentence:

Tags: phrase-request

"She IS going to be sleeping at 7 in the morning!"  I am a Spanish speaker and there is something I don´t understand in this sentence, even though I am aware it is correctly writen: If the verb **to be** is clearly mentioned, in Spanish I   don´t find a translation fot the word **IS** , I   don´t even know if it plays the role of a preposition or not.
Can you help?

Comment: The Spanish equivalent is *Ella **va** a dormir a las siete de la mañana.* Don't worry about "is" ... your translation doesn't have be literal to six decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

The Spanish equivalent is "Ella va a estar durmiendo / Ella estará durmiendo a las siete de la mañana". Both the English and the Spanish sentences are used to refer to what is expected to be happening "at a certain point" in the future.

This tense is known as future progressive or future continuous, and has the peculiarity of expressing an action in progress at some specific moment in the future. Notice that we generally say: She will sleep from 1 AM to 8 AM tomorrow (future simple). That being the case, if somebody asks: Can she come to a meeting at 7 AM tomorrow?, the answer will be: At that time tomorrow she will be sleeping (NOT: *At that time tomorrow she will sleep)

Comment: Thank you Gustavson, can you tell me why in English and in the same sentence : "She IS going to be sleeping at 7 in the morning!" one have to use "IS" since the verb "to be" is clearly stated? (I know I can use will).

Comment: @claudiosepulveda Note that the pronoun "one" is singular. Above, you should have said: "one HAS to use..." In reply to your question, "is going to" indicates future, similar to "will": "She is going to sleep" is similar to "She will sleep." If you need to express what I stated in Spanish in my answer above, that is, an action in progress in the future, instead of "She will be sleeping" (*Ella estará durmiendo*) you can replace "will" with "is going to," and the result will be: "She is going to be sleeping" (*Ella va a estar durmiendo*). Is that clear now? If it is, thanks for upvoting.

Comment: Thank you again, and you are absolutely right, I should have said "one has". I understand everything you´ve said in your two previous answers, however, I believe my question remain unanswered. What is the word "IS" doing in that sentence, what does it mean? What is its role?

Comment: @claudiosepulveda "is" forms part of "is going to." In a sentence like: "She is going to bed," "is going " is the **main verb** and "is" is translated as *está*: *Ella está yendo a la cama (a dormir)*. BUT when you find an infinitive after "is going to," in this case, the verb "be sleeping" (*estar durmiendo*), "is going to" is no longer the main verb but a future form that cannot be translated word by word, but just as *va*: *Ella va a estar durmiendo*.

Answer (score 0):

**is** -- This the third person singular present of be.  She be sleeping at seven, is simply not the right usage. **Going to** is a modal verb and  means:  [LINK-Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/going-to)

> intending to do something in the future, or being certain or expecting
>   to happen in the future.

It could just as easily be said, "She will be sleeping at seven."

These tenses are confusing but the future action is often used with a present verb.